# Mathjax live preview for version 3

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I'm using the latest version of Mathjax (3) and am looking for a feature that was demonstrated in version 2.7. The ability to [render a preview of latex input](https://cdn.rawgit.com/mathjax/MathJax/2.7.1/test/sample-dynamic.html) is useful when submitting forms, but I am unable to figure out the equivalent implementation in Mathjax version 3.

I'm not sure whether the required features are available yet -- the [upgrade notes](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/upgrading/v2.html) warn of incompatibilities but I'm not sure whether this is the cause.

There's reference to "dynamic content" on [this page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html) but the content is sparse and marked as "under construction."

I can roll back to version 2 in order to have live rendering, but I'm interested in migrating to version 3.

Comment: I'm running a local copy of Mathjax installed using NPM. I can switch between 2 and 3 locally; see https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/installation.html#obtaining-mathjax-via-npm

Comment: Are you looking for https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/input-tex2chtml.html or something more involved?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger - I was looking for dynamic rendering but in retrospect that wasn't what the link I included does; what you've provided suffices to address my need. If you want to share your link as an answer I will mark it as such. Thanks for the URL.

Comment: You can update your question with more info on what kind of dynamic behavior you are looking for. E.g., do you need updates on each keystroke? Should the input area expect only TeX-input (as in the link) or do you expect a mix of text and TeX, etc.

Comment: The link you provided https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/input-tex2chtml.html is what I was looking for. I wanted to verify the Latex input before submitting a form which redirects to a different page. 

Rendering the output as the user types isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example from https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/input-tex2chtml.html seems to be what you're looking for.

```js
  function convert() {
      var input = document.getElementById("input").value.trim();
      var display = document.getElementById("display");
      var button = document.getElementById("render");
      button.disabled = display.disabled = true;
      output = document.getElementById('output');
      output.innerHTML = '';
      MathJax.texReset();
      var options = MathJax.getMetricsFor(output);
      options.display = display.checked;
      MathJax.tex2chtmlPromise(input, options).then(function (node) {
        output.appendChild(node);
        MathJax.startup.document.clear();
        MathJax.startup.document.updateDocument();
      }).catch(function (err) {
        output.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(err.message));
      }).then(function () {
        button.disabled = display.disabled = false;
      });
    }
```

```html
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
<textarea id="input" rows="10" cols="70">
%
% Enter TeX commands below
%
x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.
</textarea>
<br />
<div class="left">
<input type="checkbox" id="display" checked onchange="convert()"> <label for="display">Display style</label>
</div>
<div class="right">
<input type="button" value="Render TeX" id="render" onclick="convert()" />
</div>
<br clear="all" />
<div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: StackOverflow security policies are interferring when running the code in the embedded "run code snippet" view. Try using the code elsewhere or run the snippet in the page and then click the "Full Page" link.